# Oracle SQL full path hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for solution how to select with use of sys_connect_by_path only full hierarchy 'branches'. I found such example on the Internet, but as result is presented it lacks second query which interests me. Example below. Does anyone know how can i achieve second form of output - full hierarchy skipping shorter ones ?

```
  SQL>
    SQL> column  full_path format a40
    SQL>
    SQL> select  ename
      2  ,       connect_by_root ename            as Designer
      3  ,       sys_connect_by_path(ename,' > ') as full_path
      4  from    emp
      5  start   with job = 'Designer'
      6  connect by prior empno = mgr;

    ENAME    DESIGNER FULL_PATH
    -------- -------- ----------------------------------------
    Jane     Jane      > Jane
    Smart    Jane      > Jane > Smart
    Ana      Jane      > Jane > Smart > Ana
    Fake     Jane      > Jane > Fake
    Tom      Jane      > Jane > Fake > Tom
    Black    Black     > Black
    Jack     Black     > Black > Jack
    Wil      Black     > Black > Wil
    Mary     Black     > Black > Mary
    Take     Black     > Black > Take
    Jane     Black     > Black > Jane
    Chris    Chris     > Chris
    Mike     Chris     > Chris > Mike
    Peter    Peter     > Peter
    Jane     Peter     > Peter > Jane
    Smart    Peter     > Peter > Jane > Smart
    Ana      Peter     > Peter > Jane > Smart > Ana
    Fake     Peter     > Peter > Jane > Fake
    Tom      Peter     > Peter > Jane > Fake > Tom

    ENAME    DESIGNER FULL_PATH
    -------- -------- ----------------------------------------
    Black    Peter     > Peter > Black
    Jack     Peter     > Peter > Black > Jack
    Wil      Peter     > Peter > Black > Wil
    Mary     Peter     > Peter > Black > Mary
    Take     Peter     > Peter > Black > Take
    Jane     Peter     > Peter > Black > Jane
    Chris    Peter     > Peter > Chris
    Mike     Peter     > Peter > Chris > Mike
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF` pseudocolumn](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns001.htm#i1007332) to filter to only those rows that are at the leaf of the hierarchy tree:

```
select  ename
,       connect_by_root ename            as Designer
,       sys_connect_by_path(ename,' > ') as full_path
from    emp
WHERE   CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
start   with job = 'Designer'
connect by prior empno = mgr;
```

Comment: hi I can accept in 5 minutes and surely will do as it works. Thank you! One more question... can i get rid off of first (parent) node displayed in hierarchy ?

Comment: Just take the substring starting from the second item - something like `SUBSTR( sys_connect_by_path(ename,' > '), INSTR( ' > ', 1, 2 ) )` - assuming you will always have at least 2 levels to your hierarchy

Comment: I am not sure if I missed something but I get it working only when INSTR get the same string as SUBSTR so in that case:

`(SUBSTR( sys_connect_by_path(ename,' > '), INSTR(sys_connect_by_path(ename,' > '), ' > ', 1, 2 ) )`

Now question is if that second occurence of sys_connect_by_path can be replaced with some alias ?

Comment: @kolboc My mistake, yes, that is what I had intended to write but just missed out that term.